# Mongoose connection error when using db name in connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to connect to Mongo instance using this connection string

`mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/`

everything works, however, when I try to specify the database name in the connection string

i.e
 `mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/storefont`

I get the following error **MongoDB Connection Error: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specify the authentication database like this:

```
mongodb://root:password@localhost:27017/storefont?authSource=admin
```

If you specify a database then this database is also taken for authentication by default. The MongoDB documentation is not 100% clear in that topic.

See also [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)

Comment: I was missing "?authSource=admin", been googling for hours. :D sent an up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Wernfield is correct. I am providing a small tweak along with an example to connect to a replica set:

When using the `authSource` query param, please ensure that the connection string is wrapped in single quotes OR just use `--authenticationDatabase` argument instead,

```
mongo mongodb://ip1:27017,ip2:27017,ip3:27017/my-db --authenticationDatabase admin -u myUsername -p myPassword
```